# How to run the Distinct command with ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

Given the following `orders` collection (the first two orders have the same `issuer`)...

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55d9ab6391fc103256107f15"), "issuer": ObjectId("55d0f641a100000401b7e454"), "description": "one" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55d9ab6391fc103256107f16"), "issuer": ObjectId("55d0f641a100000401b7e454"), "description": "two" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55d9ab6391fc103256107f17"), "issuer": ObjectId("55d0f641a100000401b7e477"), "description": "three" }
```

... I need to get a `List[String]` containing the ids of the orders associated with `issuer` 55d0f641a100000401b7e454, so I've defined the `Distinct` command like this:

```
package object commands {

  import reactivemongo.bson.{BSONString, BSONDocument}
  import reactivemongo.core.commands.{CommandError, BSONCommandResultMaker, Command}

  case class Distinct(
    collectionName: String,
    field: String,
    query: Option[BSONDocument] = None
  ) extends Command[List[String]] {

    override def makeDocuments = BSONDocument(
      "distinct" -> BSONString(collectionName),
      "key" -> field,
      "query" -> query
    )

    val ResultMaker = Distinct
  }

  object Distinct extends BSONCommandResultMaker[List[String]] {

    def apply(document: BSONDocument) = CommandError.checkOk(
      document,
      Some("distinct")
    ).toLeft(document.getAs[List[String]]("values").getOrElse(List.empty))
  }
}
```

Finally, I invoke it like this:

```
def distinct(collectionName: String, field: String, selector: BSONDocument): Future[List[String]] = {
   ReactiveMongoPlugin.db.command(Distinct(
     collectionName, field, Some(selector)
   )).recover {
     case e: LastError => throw DaoErrors.DatabaseError(collectionName, e)
   }
 }

...

val query = BSONDocument("issuer" -> BSONObjectID("55d0f641a100000401b7e454")) 
distinct("orders", "_id", query).map { orderIds =>
  // orderIds should contain the order ids... but it is empty
}
```

The problem is that `CommandError.checkOk.toLeft` in my `Distinct` object always return `None`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use ReactiveMongo AggregationFramework, it should look something like this:

   ```
   import play.modules.reactivemongo.json.commands.JSONAggregationFramework._

   val query = Json.obj("issuer" -> Json.obj("$oid" -> "55d0f641a100000401b7e454"))

   collection.aggregate(Match(query), 
       List(Group(JsNull)("fieldName" -> AddToSet("someField")))
   )
   ```

   It has been evolving in resent releases.
2. Or in your case, why not just use find with projection.

   If I understand _id is the order id, so why go the distance, if simple find is enough.

Comment: Unfortunately I use an old version of ReactiveMongo and the statements above do not compile. Anyway, my command returns `{"values":[{"$oid":"55d0f641a100000401b7e454"}],"stats":{"n":1,"nscanned":1,"nscannedObjects":1,"timems":0,"cursor":"BtreeCursor projectId_1"},"ok":1.0}`... and is the statement `document.getAs[List[String]]("values")` that actually fails, probably because it doesn't find an appropriate writer.

Comment: What about the 2nd statement? You can always update :)

Comment: For old version, you can have a look at the example mentioned at https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/issues/155